# Missing String Value Interpolation SAS

Tags: sas, missing-data

I have a series of string values with missing observations.  I would like to use flat substitution.  For instance variable x has 3 available values.  There should be a 33.333% chance that a missing value will be assigned to the available values for x under this substitution method. How would I do this?

```
DATA have;
 INPUT id a $ b $ c $ x; 
CARDS; 
1 Y Male . 5 
2 Y Female . 4 
3 . Female Tall 4 
4 Y . Short 2 
5 N Male Tall 1
;
Run;
```

Comment: You should include an example of your data.  What part of this you you need help with?  Selecting random values?  Selecting discrete values?  Joining data?

Comment: Sorry about that I am still a little new.

Comment: The issues I had was with Sorry about that I am still a little new to this end of Stackoverflow.
My data looks like the following:My data looks like the following:
DATA have;
INPUT id a $ b $ c $ x;
CARDS;
1 Y Male . 5
2 Y Female . 4
3 . Female Tall 4
4 Y . Short 2
5 N Male Tall 1;
Run;

I need help figuring out building code to select multiple variables with missing values.

Comment: Hi.  Imputation of missing values is a complicated concept and not appropriate for a simple StackOverflow question.  I suggest you search for "imputation" and "character" at minimum and see what you find, and then if you have a more *specific* question come back here and ask it.

Comment: Thank you. However, I have not posed a question regarding the implications of which interpolation method is superior in which instance. My only concern is how to perform a method of data handling that substitutes one value for a missing value within a dataset. The data handling itself is necessary to perform one given form, but perhaps other methods of, interpolation.

Comment: @Halo8tds You're still expected to ask a coding question, not "how do I do this", here. I don't see any code.  The data you provided is helpful - but if you're just asking "how do I do this", again, search!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this with generating random numbers and hard coding the limits. There should be an easier way to do this, but for the purposes of the question this should work.

```
option missing=''; 
data begin;
input a $; 
cards;
a
. 
b 
c
. 
e
. 
f 
g 
h 
. 
. 
j
. 
;
run;

data intermediate;
    set begin;
    if a EQ '' then help= rand("uniform");
    else help=.;
run;

data wanted; 
    set intermediate;
    format help populated.;

    if a EQ '' then do;
        if         0<=help<0.33 then a='V1';
        else if 0.33<=help<0.66 then a='V2';
        else if 0.66<=help      then a='V3';
    end;
    drop help;
run;
```

Comment: The issues I had was with Sorry about that I am still a little new to this end of Stackoverflow.
My data looks like the following:My data looks like the following:
DATA have;
INPUT id a $ b $ c $ x;
CARDS;
1 Y Male . 5
2 Y Female . 4
3 . Female Tall 4
4 Y . Short 2
5 N Male Tall 1;
Run;

I need help figuring out building code to select multiple variables with missing values.

Answer (score 1):

You could use temporary arrays to store the possible values.  Then generate a random index into the array.

```
DATA have;
 INPUT id a $ b $ c $ x; 
CARDS; 
1 Y Male . 5 
2 Y Female . 4 
3 . Female Tall 4 
4 Y . Short 2 
5 N Male Tall 1
;

data want ;
  set have ;
  array possible_b (2) $8 ('Male','Female') ;
  if missing(b) then b=possible_b(1+int(rand('uniform')*dim(possible_b)));
run;
```